# Android, best way to push data to a set of subscribed threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

On Android (Java), I am having trouble conceptually with the best way to provide the following.  I have a thread which polls for packets from an interface, reading them in as they are available.  Then, I have a set of threads which should operate on each packet as they arrive (different threads have different operations).

What I am imagining is a thread should be able to "subscribe" to the packet data on the main thread, and get a copy of each packet as it arrives.  I do not mind (and might prefer) if the data is copied to each of the "subscribed" threads.  That way, i do not have to worry about the threads synchronizing some sort of cleanup of shared data.

Is the best way to do this to have the main thread to maintain a list of callback functions and execute them on each packet?  But, if that's the case, how do I ensure the functions are executed on the "slave" threads?  Is there another/better way to do this that anyone can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution might be to register broadcast receivers for the events you're interested in communicating, and then have the initial data packet processor broadcast intents as appropriate.  Take a look at http://justanapplication.wordpress.com for a detailed series of posts (8 and counting) on Intents, as well as the following two pages from the dev guide.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html